# Dimensions of 2d char array from ArrayDeque Object

Tags: java, casting, arraydeque

I have a method that takes a char[][] as a parameter (basically a NxN grid of chars) and is utilizing an ArrayDeque in order to look through the whole 2d array. I want the row and column of a char[][] object removed from the ArrayDeque, and currently use this:

```
             ArrayDeque stack=new ArrayDeque();
             stack.push(grid[0][0]); //grid being the 2d array passed to the method
             char[][] temp=(char[][]) stack.pop(); 
             int row=temp.length-1;
             int column=temp[0].length-1;
```

This compiles in Eclipse, but when run throws a ClassCastException. Is there a way to get the row and column without the char[][] case in the second line above?

Comment: Some ClassCastExceptions are only thrown at runtime so this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `ArrayDeque` doing? *Nothing!* You add a value and you take it back.

Although, assuming `grid` is a `char[][]`, and knowing that `push()` takes an `Object`, it is implicitly auto-boxing the value.

In short, what you get is:

```
temp = (char[][])Character.valueOf(grid[0][0])
```

You are casting a `Character` to a `char[][]`, so of course you get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: The above is simplified, I am using the ArrayDeque as a stack of positions to check. It is a pathfinding algorithm so I need to check values within the grid[][] array based on their proximity to other indices.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact of why you get `ClassCastException`. You push a `Character` and cast to `char[][]`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I avoid the exception? Can I do something like:
int row=stack.pop().length-1; //this is a compiler error, but is there something similar that is not?

Comment: How about you push the entire `grid`, and not just the value in `0,0`? How about using generics, and define `stack` as `ArrayDeque<char[][]>`, so you don't have to cast?

Comment: Technically I'm not even trying to push the value in 0,0; I'm trying to use the ArrayDeque to hold coordinate pairs in the form of char[][]s, which I can then later compare to the actual contents of grid. So in hindsight (although this still leaves the same issue) my initial push should be stack.push(new char[0][0]);

Comment: You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).